# Cuando hago una llamada ajax me imprime la pagina web y no entra a la funcion

Tags: c#, ajax, servidor

Intento hacer una simple llamda ajax pero de la nada empezo a imprimirme la llamada ajax y ya no enta al webmetod y todo esta de forma correcta, no le movi nada y empezo a fallar de esa forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo ajax

```
function getRecords(idExcel, tipoFile) {
    $("#IdRecords").removeClass("hidden");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "AdminView.aspx/getInforRecords",
        data: '{idUpload:"' + idExcel + '",tipoFile:"' + tipoFile + '"}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            return;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText)
        }
    });
}
```

Codigo .aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public string  getInforRecords(int idUpload,int tipoFile)
{
    UploadGEOController geocont = new UploadGEOController();
    List<UploadGEO> listgeo = new List<UploadGEO>();
    string htmlreturn = "";

    listgeo = geocont.RecordsExcel(idUpload,tipoFile);
    List<UploadGEO> lstreturn = new List<UploadGEO>();
    //foreach (UploadGEO elemento in listgeo)
    //{
    //    htmlreturn += "<tr><td>" + elemento.AreaFuncional + "</td><td>" + elemento.DominioFuncional + "</td><td>" + elemento.Periodo + "</td><td>" + elemento.Proveedor + "</td>" +
    //    "<td> <div class='col-lg-12 text-center'><i id='ModalRecords' class='fa fa-eye' title='Aqui Usted podra ver detalles'  aria-hidden='true' style='cursor:pointer;'></i></div>" +
    //    "" +
    //    "</td></tr>";

    //}

    lstreturn.AddRange(listgeo);

    return "";

}
```

Comment: Puedes entrar a la ruta?  
http://NombreDeTuWeb/AdminView.aspx/getInforRecords

Parece que le error es que no la encuentra

Comment: "~AdminView.aspx/getInforRecords" <-- tal ves se pueda arreglar con esto